# React Native "react-native-side-menu"

Tags: react-native

I was trying to get the side menu working and i got it too function but now i'm working on getting the onPress function to work with a button click!

The error i am receiving is

"Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.menuActions.toggle')"

Which is in the TouchableOpacity!

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var SideMenu = require('react-native-side-menu');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} = React;

var Menu = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.menu}>
      <View style={styles.avatarContainer}>
        <image
          style={styles.avatar}
          source={{
            uri: 'http://pickaface.net/includes/themes/clean/img/slide2.png'
          }}/>
          <Text style={styles.yourname}> Your Name </Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.menuitem}> About </Text>
        <Text style={styles.menuitem}> Music </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
});

var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.props.menuActions.toggle}>
        <Text style={this.props.style}>{this.props.children}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
})

var Layout = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <SideMenu menu={<Menu />}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Welcome To React Native!
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Button style={styles.button}> Open Menu </Button>
      </SideMenu>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Tabs_Boilerplate', () => Layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must tell react that you are going to want to use the menuActions object that is on the context

```
var Button = React.createClass({
    contextTypes = {
        menuActions: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.context.menuActions.toggle}>
                <Text style={this.props.style}>{this.props.children}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
})
```

Alternatively they recently added the ability to control if the menu is open via props. This is done by simply adding a "isOpen" prop on the side menu object and updating that prop to true/false depending on if you want the menu open or not.